# In NestJS, how to get execution context or request instance in custom method decorator?

Tags: decorator, nestjs

I have a custom method decorator like this.

```
export function CustomDecorator() {

    return applyDecorators(
        UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    );
}
```

Inside the Custom Decorator, I want to get the Request Header but not sure how to get the Request Instance?

Comment: Could add more info about what do you wanna do, please? I got it that you want to access headers but with what purpose?

Comment: We have a shared auth module in which we can have JWT or GoogleAuth. I want to implement a custom decorator which applies different guards based on the request headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't be able to get the `ExectuionContext` object or the `Request` object in a class or method decorator, because these decorators are run immediately at the moment of import. What should be done instead is to make a `SuperGuard` that does have the `ExecutionContext` available to it. This `SuperGuard` should have all of the other guards injected into it via the `constructor` and depending on the header you should call/return the result from the guard called. Something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SuperGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtAuthGuard: JwtAuthGuard,
    private readonly googleAuthGuard: GoogleAuthGuard,
  ) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    if (req.headers['whatever'] === 'google') {
      return this.googleAuthGuard.canActivate(context);
    } else {
      return this.jwtAuthGuard.canActivate(context);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay, I get this error.

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RomeGuard (?). Please make sure that the argument JwtAuthGuard at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If JwtAuthGuard is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If JwtAuthGuard is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtAuthGuard */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules

Comment: You'll need to make sure that wherever you use `SuperGuard` you have `JwtAuthGuard` and `GoogleAuthGuard` added as `providers`. This can be done from a `GuardModule` if you so choose

Comment: Hi Jay, I added it like this `providers: [SharedDataAuthService, JwtStrategy, JwtAuthGuard],` but it's showing that error.

Comment: All good Jay. I need to add it into exports as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Jay, I have a question... If the Guard decorator run immediately at the moment of import, how could it catch the request in executionContext ? ^^

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access the execution context within decorator using `Inject` inside decorator's factory.
Here is my decorator that swallows errors produced by method and returns predefined value in case of exception.

```js
import { Injectable, Scope, Inject, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CONTEXT } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class ExceptionsHandler {
  public constructor(@Inject(CONTEXT) private readonly context: ExecutionContext) {}

  private integrationsRequestErrors: unknown[] = [];

  public handle(error: unknown): void {
    // ADD error to context if necessary
    this.integrationsRequestErrors.push(error);
  }
}

export const ErrorSwallower = (options: {
  serviceImplementation: string;
  defaultValue: unknown;
  errorMessage?: string;
}): MethodDecorator => {
  const { defaultValue, integration } = options;
  const Injector = Inject(ExceptionsHandler);
  return (target: object, _propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    Injector(target, 'exceptionsHandler');
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: unknown[]) {
      const exceptionHandler = this.experiment as ExceptionsHandler;
      try {
        const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        if (result && result instanceof Promise) {
          return result.catch((error: unknown) => {
            exceptionHandler.handle({ error, integration });
            return defaultValue;
          });
        }
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        exceptionHandler.handle({ error, integration });
        return defaultValue;
      }
    };
  };
};
```

and here is the code above put into action:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  @ErrorSwallower({ serviceImplementation: 'ExampleClass', defaultValue: [] })
  private async getSomeData(args: IGetSomeDataArgs): Promise<ISomeData[]> {
    throw new Error('Oops');
  }
}
```